# LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates() throws IllegalArgumentException, while the emulator has internet

Tags: android, genymotion, locationmanager

I checked my emulator (Genymotion) and it has internet. But, when I try to get location based on network, I get this exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider doesn't exist: network`

I also checked the connectivity in my code and it returns true:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20660561/5923990) because I know I can avoid the exception with a simple if. But, my question is why provider is not available while I have internet?